# Hashmap NullPointerException

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, hashmap, dijkstra

[image]Test gives NullPointer Exception even though I think I should have correctly populated the Map. 
I am trying to implement a Graph which is a set of vertices and the set of edges. Each vertise also has a HashMap of adjacent Vertices together with the weight of the edge.

```
    public class TownGraphManagerTest {
            private TownGraphManager graph;
            private String[] town;

            @Before
            public void setUp() throws Exception {
                graph = new TownGraphManager();
                town = new String[12];

                for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                    town[i] = "Town_" + i;
                    graph.addTown(town[i]);
                }

                graph.addRoad(town[1], town[2], "Road_1");
                graph.addRoad(town[1], town[3], "Road_2");
                graph.addRoad(town[1], town[5], "Road_3");
                graph.addRoad(town[3], town[7], "Road_4");
                graph.addRoad(town[3], town[8], "Road_5");
                graph.addRoad(town[4], town[8], "Road_6");
                graph.addRoad(town[6], town[9], "Road_7");
                graph.addRoad(town[9], town[10], "Road_8");
                graph.addRoad(town[8], town[10], "Road_9");
                graph.addRoad(town[5], town[10], "Road_10");
                graph.addRoad(town[10], town[11], "Road_11");
                graph.addRoad(town[2], town[11], "Road_12");
                graph.addRoad(town[7], town[6], "Road_13");



            }
            @After
            public void tearDown() throws Exception {
                graph = null;
            }
    @Test
        public void testGetPath() {
            ArrayList<String> path = graph.getPath(town[1],town[11]);
            assertNotNull(path);
            assertTrue(path.size() > 0);

            assertEquals("Town_2 via Road_12 to Town_11 1 
            mi",path.get(0).trim());
            assertEquals("Town_1 via Road_1 to Town_2 
1mi",path.get(1).trim());

        }
    }
```

This is the class that actually add the entry into the map in the addDestination() method.

```
    public class Town implements Comparable<Town>{

    private String name;
    private Integer distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private Map<Town, Integer> adjTowns;
    private Set<Road> adjRoads;
    private LinkedList<Town> shortestPath = new LinkedList<Town>();
    /**
     * 
     */
    public Town() {
        super();
        this.adjTowns=new HashMap<Town, Integer>();
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public Town(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adjTowns=new HashMap<Town, Integer>();
    }

    /**
     * @return the adjTowns
     */
    public Map<Town, Integer> getAdjTowns() {
        return adjTowns;
    }


    /**
     * @param adjTowns the adjTowns to set
     */
    public void setAdjTowns(Map<Town, Integer> adjTowns) {
        this.adjTowns=new HashMap<Town, Integer>();
        this.adjTowns = adjTowns;
    }


    public void addDestination(Town destination, int distance) {
        this.adjTowns.put(destination, distance);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object t){
        return this.toString().hashCode()==t.toString().hashCode();

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Town o) {

        return this.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getName());
    }

    /**
     * @return the shortestPath
     */
    public LinkedList<Town> getShortestPath() {
        return shortestPath;
    }

    /**
     * @param shortestPath the shortestPath to set
     */
    public void setShortestPath(LinkedList<Town> shortestPath) {
        this.shortestPath = shortestPath;
    }

}
```

I also implemented a Graph class which passes similar tests

```
public class Graph<V, E> implements GraphInterface<Town, Road>{

    private HashSet<Town> vert;
    private HashSet<Road> edges;


    Graph(){
        vert=new HashSet<Town>();
        edges=new HashSet<Road>();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#getEdge(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Road getEdge(Town sourceVertex, Town destinationVertex) {


        for(Road r: edges){
            if(((r.getVert1().compareTo(sourceVertex)==0)
                    &&(r.getVert2().compareTo(destinationVertex)==0))
                    ||((r.getVert2().compareTo(sourceVertex)==0)
                            &&(r.getVert1().compareTo(destinationVertex)==0)))
                return r;

        }
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#addEdge(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Road addEdge(Town sourceVertex, Town destinationVertex, int weight, String description) {
        Road temp=new Road (sourceVertex, destinationVertex,  weight,  description);
        edges.add(temp);
        sourceVertex.addDestination(destinationVertex, weight);
        destinationVertex.addDestination(sourceVertex, weight);

        return temp;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#addVertex(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addVertex(Town v) {

        return vert.add(v);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#containsEdge(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean containsEdge(Town sourceVertex, Town destinationVertex) {
        for(Road r: edges){
            if(r.contains(sourceVertex)&&r.contains(destinationVertex))
                return true;

        }
        return false;

    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#edgesOf(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Road> edgesOf(Town vertex) {
        Set<Road> res=new HashSet<Road>();
        for(Road t: this.edges){
            if(t.contains(vertex))
                res.add(t);
        }
        return res;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#removeEdge(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Road removeEdge(Town sourceVertex, Town destinationVertex, int weight, String description) {
        Road temp=new Road (sourceVertex, destinationVertex,  weight,  description);

        edges.remove(temp);
        return new Road (sourceVertex, destinationVertex,  weight,  description);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#removeVertex(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeVertex(Town v) {
        return vert.remove(v);

    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#shortestPath(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> shortestPath(Town sourceVertex, Town destinationVertex) {
        for(Road r:this.edgeSet())
        {
            this.addEdge(r.getVert1(), r.getVert2(), r.getDistance(), r.getName());
            r.getVert1().addDestination(r.getVert2(), r.getDistance());
            r.getVert2().addDestination(r.getVert1(), r.getDistance());
        }





        dijkstraShortestPath(sourceVertex)  ;
        ArrayList<String> shortestPath=new ArrayList<String>();
        LinkedList<Town> shortestPath1=destinationVertex.getShortestPath();
        for(int i=0;i<shortestPath1.size()-1;i++){
            shortestPath.add(shortestPath1.get(i).toString()+" via "
                    + ""+this.getEdge(shortestPath1.get(i), shortestPath1.get(i+1))+" to "
                    + shortestPath1.get(i+1).getName() 
                    +" " + this.getEdge(shortestPath1.get(i), shortestPath1.get(i+1)).getDistance()
                    +" mi");
        }
        shortestPath.add(shortestPath1.getLast().toString()+" via "
                + ""+this.getEdge(shortestPath1.getLast(), destinationVertex)+" to "
                + destinationVertex.getName() 
                +" " + this.getEdge(shortestPath1.getLast(), destinationVertex).getDistance()
                +" mi");
        Collections.reverse(shortestPath);
        for(Town a:destinationVertex.getShortestPath()){
            System.out.print(a.getName()+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        return shortestPath;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see GraphInterface#dijkstraShortestPath(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void dijkstraShortestPath(Town startVertex) {
        startVertex.setDistance(0);

        Set<Town> settledNodes = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Town> unsettledNodes = this.vert;

        unsettledNodes.add(startVertex);

        while (unsettledNodes.size() != 0) {
            Town currentNode = getLowestDistanceNode(unsettledNodes);
            unsettledNodes.remove(currentNode);
            for (Entry < Town, Integer> adjacencyPair : currentNode.getAdjTowns().entrySet()) {
                Town adjacentNode = adjacencyPair.getKey();
                Integer edgeWeight = adjacencyPair.getValue();
                if (!settledNodes.contains(adjacentNode)) {
                    CalculateMinimumDistance(adjacentNode, edgeWeight, currentNode);
                    unsettledNodes.add(adjacentNode);
                }
            }
            settledNodes.add(currentNode);
        }


    }

    private static Town getLowestDistanceNode(Set < Town > unsettledNodes) {
        Town lowestDistanceNode = null;
        int lowestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Town node: unsettledNodes) {
            int nodeDistance = node.getDistance();
            if (nodeDistance < lowestDistance) {
                lowestDistance = nodeDistance;
                lowestDistanceNode = node;
            }
        }
        return lowestDistanceNode;
    }

    private static void CalculateMinimumDistance(Town evaluationNode,Integer 
edgeWeigh, Town sourceNode) {
        Integer sourceDistance = sourceNode.getDistance();
        if (sourceDistance + edgeWeigh < evaluationNode.getDistance()) {
            evaluationNode.setDistance(sourceDistance + edgeWeigh);
            LinkedList<Town> shortestPath  = new LinkedList<>
(sourceNode.getShortestPath());
            shortestPath.add(sourceNode);
            evaluationNode.setShortestPath(shortestPath);
        }
    }





}
```

[image]

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: ``for (Entry < Town, Integer> adjacencyPair : currentNode.getAdjTowns().entrySet()) {
    Town adjacentNode = adjacencyPair.getKey();
    Integer edgeWeight = adjacencyPair.getValue();
    if (!settledNodes.contains(adjacentNode)) {
     CalculateMinimumDistance(adjacentNode, edgeWeight, currentNode);
     unsettledNodes.add(adjacentNode);
    }
   }``

Comment: Have you tried printing `currentNode` to the console to see if that variable is null?

Comment: It wont populate adjTowns<Town, Integer>

Comment: Print `currentNode` to the console to verify that it is not null.

Comment: Yes, its prints null because adjTowns is empty. For some reason with GraphTest it works just fine, so i literally followed Graph class implementation and it wont work

Comment: It doesn't matter if `adjTowns` is empty if `currentNode` is null.

Comment: Its really weird, because it works just fine with exact same test for Graph class